# Is there a more efficient/elegant way of changing data from a function in a switch-case?

Tags: javascript, memory, ecmascript-6

I have an array of users in this case that I'd like to alter based on the result of a switch-case. Right now I return the new users array and use that, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant approach to this.

I have simplified the code to just 1 case in this example.

```js
let users = []

switch (message) {
  case 'change_name': {
    const { newUsers } =
      changeName(id, name, users)

    users = newUsers

    return
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have some more cases in the switch statement?

Comment: What do the actions within switch statements share in common

Comment: I always like using an object literal as a lookup when doing this sort of stuff.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes i do, i just simplified the code in this case

Comment: the rest is importan, if you have same calls.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri they all alter the users array based on a given user id

Comment: It's *too* simplified, in this case. At least give us 2-3 cases. It's hard to generalise from one.

Comment: and just out of curiosity, what does `changeName` ? I mean, what is all that code about exactly? Changes what exactly?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it alters the name of a user in the array based on the given user id and new name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually chose to use classes instead of just an array. I can now call `users.update()` within the `changeName` function.

```js
class Users {
  data = []

  update (data) {
    this.data = data
  }
}

const users = new Users()

switch (message) {
  case 'change_name': {
    return changeName(id, name, users)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to change the `changeName` function you could let it return the users array instead of an object. If this is possible you can do it like so:

```
users = changeName(id, name, users)
```

Comment: this wouldn't work in my case because sometimes I need to alter more than 1 array, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Maybe you can reference the users array so if you change it inside the function it will be changed everywhere.